# Compile a dynamic directive inside a template

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a directive like this:

```
foldeskApp.directive('contributionFooter', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'C',
        template: '<button type="button" class="btn" ng-class="{\'btn-success\': canCreate()}">Add</button>'
    };
});
```

And a controller like this:

```
foldeskApp.controller('MainCtrl',
    ['Auth', '$scope', function(Auth, $scope) {
    $scope.footerType = 'contribution';
}]);
```

Can I call the directive like this?

```
<div class="modal-footer {{footerType}}-footer"></div>
```

Comment: The code seem fine for me... Have you encounted any problem running it?

Comment: I'm fairly certain that you cannot. Angular compiles the DOM before it interpolates the expressions

Comment: @LinhPham It simply doesn't compile it at all...

Comment: This does not work for the reason @NewDev states. The directives to be compiled need to be strictly defined in the HTML. You cannot use a variable for directives anywhere else and a class based directive is no exception. If the value ever changed you would need to recompile that element again and that is dome something Angular does for you. Your best bet would be to use ng-include with and have different templates that use transclusion.

Answer (score 0):

You need to compile the DOM using the $compile service.

Here's an example of how to achieve that, although I'm not a fan of using $timeout here:

http://codepen.io/jlowcs/pen/jEKKjZ

HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <div class="modal-footer {{footerType}}-footer"></div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
angular.module('exampleApp', [])
.directive('contributionFooter', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'C',
        template: '<button type="button" class="btn" ng-class="{\'btn-success\': canCreate()}">Add</button>'
    };
})
.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $element, $timeout, $compile) {
    $scope.footerType = 'contribution';

    //timeout to do it when {{footerType}} has been replaced
    //but it would probably be best to do this in a link function in a directive
    $timeout(function () {
      $compile($element.children())($scope);
    });
});

angular.bootstrap(document, ['exampleApp']);
```

Comment: So, I would recommend creating a directive for that modal-footer tag, so that you can do the compile call inside its link function.